# Is there any good way to read numbers in square brackets in Lua?

Tags: input, lua

In Lua, Is there any good way to read Only numbers from input like "[1,2,3,4]" if i know the number of the numbers

I did io.read("*n") for each, but that just returns nil values

```
local num = io.read()
for i = 1, num do
    print(io.read("*n"))
end
```

for that code inputs are

```
4
[1,1,15,54]
```

outputs are

```
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

I expect

```
1
1
15
54
```

Should I just use string.find and sub with ',' ?

Comment: Are you really asking "How do I parse JSON in Lua?" If you are, you might want to avoid re-inventing that wheel: https://luarocks.org/search?q=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that there are no spaces in the input, you can use this code:

```
local num = io.read()
for i = 1, num do
    io.read(1)
    print(io.read("*n"))
end
```

The first `io.read(1)` reads `[`, the next ones read the commas. The closing `]` is left unread.

Reading the whole line and parsing it is more robust:

```
local num = io.read()
local lin = io.read()
local i=0
for w in lin:gmatch("%d+") do
    i=i+1
    print(i,w)
end
```